# How to extract forum channel ID from message using discordjs 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there any way to determine if a message is coming from a text channel or a forum channel? I'm using Discord.js v14, and I need to know the ID of the forum channel. However, using `message.channel.id` only gives me the ID of the post, not the parent forum channel ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the channel's type where the message is coming from is `PublicThread`. Although it still can be a thread in a text channel so you'll also need to check the parent channel's type. If it's `GuildForum`, the message is sent in a forum thread. To get the forum channel ID, you can use [`message.channel.parentId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ThreadChannel?scrollTo=parentId).

```js
if (
  message.channel.type === ChannelType.PublicThread &&
  message.channel.parent?.type === ChannelType.GuildForum
) {
  console.log(`This message is sent in a forum thread (ID: ${message.channel.parentId})`);
}
```

Don't forget to import `ChannelType` from `discord.js`.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```js
client.on(Events.MessageCreate, (interaction) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(interaction));
  const {channelId} = interaction;
  if (channelId === 'somechanelID') {
    //do something
  }
});
```